# Change height of Tab bar of the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Right now i m doing this :

```
   <style name="FapiaoTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">

            <!-- HEIGHT OF THE WHOLE BAR -->
            <item name="android:actionBarSize">80dip</item>

    </style>    

    <!-- TAB  -->
    <style name="MyTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">

                <!-- TAB HEIGHT -->
        <item name="android:minHeight">50dip</item>

    </style>
```

With this code, the height of the title bar should be 80 - 50 = 30 dpi.

But instead of that, the title bar get always the same height of the tab bar.

Any ideas ?